# Sed: Including an external file specified by regex

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I would like insert a file into another file using `sed`. Here is an example

I have a file `input.txt` which has the line:

`#INCLUDE filename-to-import`

Currently I am processing this with `sed` to create `output.txt`

```
sed -r -e "/^#INCLUDE (\w+)/r ${HOME}/inc/<filename>.sh" input.txt
```

How can I back reference the group captured in the regex in order to import the `filename-to-import` that is specified? I tried using `\1` but that didn't work, I believe because it is outside of the regex scope. `$1` didn't work either.

Is this possible with `sed`?

Comment: Fairly sure this is not possible with `sed`, `awk` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

As said, I don't think this can be done with `sed`. Here is an `awk` one liner instead:

```
awk '$1 == "#INCLUDE" { while(getline line <$2){print line} }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^~INCLUDE (\w+)/{p;s##cat /inc/\1.sh#e}' file
```

Capture a back reference using the substitute command and in the RHS of it, evaluate a shell command, using the `e` flag.

Comment: I have always had trouble with the `e` flag, nice usage example.